# Unprivileged user namespace required for Brave browser to run on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, security, browser

I recently set up a Debian 10.4 Buster/Windows 10 dual boot machine. I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/@connorrfin10/how-to-install-brave-browser-on-debian-10-buster-f95c9d30556c)
exactly, which instructs you to run the following command in order to be able to run Brave browser on Debian 10:

```bsh
echo 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1' > /etc/sysctl.d/userns.conf
```

Apparently, it's mandatory; otherwise Brave browser will not launch a window when you click on it.

However, after I installed Brave, I read that according to this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209529/what-does-enabling-kernel-unprivileged-userns-clone-do), some believe the above command to be dangerous and that it will leave your Linux kernel very vulnerable.

I have a couple questions: 
(1) Is this step really mandatory for Debian 10 to launch Brave browser? Or is there some workaround?
(2) Is this really a security risk? If so, to what extent?

I have been using Brave for awhile now and am very much a fan of its privacy features, speed, and overall performance. It would be ironic if in order to get it to work on my Linux distro, I have to do something that leaves my Linux kernel exposed to severe vulnerabilities?!

Comment: I opened Brave browser sometime ago in ubuntu 18 without the need of that trick. Have you tried it without doing that ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi After setting `kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=0`, I rebooted and was able to launch Brave browser still. I edited the post. Not sure why the author of that guide said it was mandatory...

Comment: Firefox uses userns when available (and in multi-process mode) and doesn't use it when not available. Can be easily verified by running `lsns -t user` in each case. Brave could have chosen the same pragmatic approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set `'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=0'` in `/etc/sysctl.d/userns.conf` to disable unprivileged user namespaces, and lo and behold, Brave browser still launched! I also tried doing a fresh install of Brave browser without executing the last command in the guide to enable unprivileged user namespaces. And again, Brave launched with no issues.

It appears that this is *not* a mandatory step after all, at least for my setup. I think that no one should be recommending that a user do this unnecessary and potentially dangerous step. It should only be done if absolutely necessary, and of course, after considering the potential risks.

Comment: It might be difficult to explain, but using user namespaces is a security layer here: if it's like Firefox is doing it's mapping for some sandboxed subprocesses the user to itself and nothing else, thus *unmapping* any other user, including root: should a remote attacker know root's password (or sudo-privileged user's password) and a way to run su or sudo through the browser's sandboxed subprocess, it still won't be able to become root if user namespaces are in place (and no apparmor around).

Comment: @A.B While that's true, it's also the case that unprivileged user namespaces open up significant attack surface into the kernel, so it's a tradeoff.